# Importing objects into a namespace in python without redefining?

Tags: python, namespaces

I'm wondering if it's possible to import objects into a namespace such as a class, etc.. so it can be referenced.  Basically removing the explicit redefinitions here:

```
import Bar

class Foo:
   X = Bar.X
   Y = Bar.Y
   Z = Bar.Z
```

I'm basically interested in being able to reference Bar.X, etc... from Foo.  from ... import ... didn't work either as expected.

Comment: @esaelPsnoroMoN To simplify and abstract a certain API

Comment: from Bar import X, Y, Z does work to import them into the current module. Could you expand on what you are trying to do? Since they are module level definitions from Bar(global) they don't make sense as instance definitions in a class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel like you should ever need to do this (It feels like a really bad idea to me).  However, if you insist, here's my attempt:

```
import module
class Foo(object):
    pass #Other stuff here

for k,v in module.__dict__.items():
    try:
       setattr(Foo,k,v)
    except AttributeError:
       pass  #read-only attributes?
```

Of course, it's up to you (the programmer) to make sure you don't overwrite any attribute of `Foo` with attributes of `module`.

---

Note that if you just want to change the name of a module on import, you can do that:

```
import Foo as Bar
```

Or you can `from import ... as name_in_this_module`.

For example, say you have something that is windows specific and a custom module which will provide the same functionality on Unix:

```
try:
    import windows_module as sys_dep_mod
except ImportError:
    import unix_module as sys_dep_mod

def myfunc(baz):
    bar = sys_dep_mod.func(baz)
    #do something with bar
    #return something
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it does accomplish what I ask however I guess you're right: it doesn't necessarily make it clear to the end user what is available in the end code analysis tools aren't able to auto-complete either.

Comment: @stgtscc -- You said above that you're trying to simplify some API.  See my edit above, it *might* be useful...